# Can I save epic project points while im not building an epic project?

Tags: simcity-2013

I was wondering, is it was possible to collect epic project points, without currently working on an epic project?

I find it really hard to collect the required 80 points, in only 24 hours, in order to collect the silver tokens. So I was hoping I could save up the points now, to contribute later.